# Is there a module for Open API code generator for Nest.js

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, nestjs, openapi-generator, nestjs-swagger

Is there any solution for Open API code generator for Nest.js such as [this maven plugin for Spring Boot](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin)?

I'd like to follow [API-First Development](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-openapi/) approache using Nest.js instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new npm package that can do it, see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-openapi-gen).

Answer (score 3):

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5518), but it was stalled pending on the person who made the changes.  I'm no good at Java, but you might be able to help out there.

Comment: This PR was merged in January 2021 and looks to be part of the latest release!

Comment: Which is great for client-side, not so much for a server stub.